# Angularjs complex layout application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, layout, view

I'm trying to set up **angularjs** into my Rails 4 app using the `Angular Seed` as default structure but I'm having a hard time getting my head around this.

My layout is made of 2 parts. The first part (left part) contain the list of products :

```
%ul
  %li{ 'ng-repeat' => 'product in products | filter:search' }
    %a{ 'ng-click' => 'open(tier)' }
      %img{ 'ng-src' => '{{ tier.logo }}' }
```

And the other part is here to display the details of a product but ALSO anything else as product edition, and the form for creating a new product. That's at that point that I'm really confused. So far, I was using `ng-switch` helper in order to get the product detail on the right side :

```
%ng-switch{ 'on' => 'details()' }
  %div{ 'ng-switch-when' => "true" }
    %header
      %span
        .h3 {{ opened.name }}
    .panel-body
      .tab-content
        .tab-pane.active
          %section.scrollable
            %img{ 'ng-src' => '{{ opened.logo_large }}' }
```

And my controller looks like this :

```
controller('TiersController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Tiers', 'ngProgress', '$timeout', function($scope, $routeParams, Tiers, ngProgress, $timeout) {
  $scope.tiers = Tiers.query();

  $scope.open = function(tier){
    if( $scope.isOpen(tier) ){
      $scope.opened = undefined;
    }else{
      $scope.opened = tier;
    }
  };

  $scope.isOpen = function(tier){
    return $scope.opened === tier;
  };

  $scope.details = function(){
    return $scope.opened !== undefined;
  };

  $scope.close = function(){
    $scope.opened = undefined;
  };
}])
```

So far, both left side (list of product) and right side (detail) are in the same view file. It works fine when I'm clicking on a product and display it's detail. But what if I want to inject another view into the right side such as a form? How can insert some kind of partial into this product layout?
The thing is, I don't want to have to write all my different view into the same file for maintainability purpose.

Hope I was clear. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for ng-include. It does what it sounds like, it includes another template into the current template.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I fixed the issue using `angular ui-router` which allow me to have nested view routes. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using **angular ui-router** https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router